# ¿Cómo posicionarse al final de un RecyclerView de Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Intento posicionarme al final de un `RecyclerView` pero lo siguiente no funciona, tampoco retorna error.

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(datos.size);
```

Comment: Prueba agregando un handler! y comentame que resultado tienes.

Comment: Hola, funciona con datos.size()-1 como bien indica @Ezequiel_Zanetta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hay varias formas de posicionarse al final de un RecyclerView. Yo suelo usar la siguiente:

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(datos.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

El primero y el último visibles dependen de `LayoutManager`. Si estás usando `LayoutManager` o `GridLayoutManager`, puedes usar las siguientes funciones:

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Por ejemplo:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int ultimaPosicion = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 1):

Además de :

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(datos.size);
```

puedes usar smoothScrollToPosition :

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(datos.size);
```

Pero realizalo dentro de un Handler:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
     mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(datos.size);
}}, 100);
```

En un ListView:

```
  getListView().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(datos.zise);
        }
    });
```